Excel Array Formula for Dynamic List / Aggregate of Non zero quantities for build of material
A simple manufacturing concept where specific parts / sub assemblies comprise of a "build of material".
I have this setup using logic in python and integrated into an ERP system but I am struggling to do the same thing or a simplified version in Excel. I am open to a better method but I am limited to excel formulas (non office 365). I do not want to use power query or something that is less navigable for the non technical.
In essence, there is a selection of options.



OPTIONS
SELECTION




CRUST
X


SAUCE
A


TOPPINGS
O



I created a massive list translating these options into Part / Qty / and basically if statements if they need to be included based on the option selections.
TABLE 1 - I AM AT THIS POINT



PART
QTY
IN BUILD




CRUST X
0.1
1


FLOUR X
0.2
1


WATER X
0.4
1


EGGS X
0.5
1


CRUST Y
0.5
0


FLOUR Y
0.5
0


WATER Y
0.5
0


EGGS Y
0.5
0


SAUCE A
0.5
1


SAUCE B
0.5
0


SAUCE C
0.5
0


SAUCE D
0.5
0


TOPPINGS L
0.2
0


TOPPINGS M
0.3
0


TOPPINGS N
0.1
0


TOPPINGS O
0.4
1



Now The Question Is - How Can I Turn These Into A Single Dynamic List Using A Formula (Without Office 365).
There Are Duplicates In The Part - In A Perfect World These Are Summed (If Non Zero)
TABLE 2 - I Cannot Figure Out How To Create



PART
QTY




CRUST X
0.1


FLOUR X
0.2


WATER X
0.4


EGGS X
0.5


SAUCE A
0.5


TOPPINGS O
0.4



Scouring the internet I found a few relatable functions using index , aggregate, and array formulas but wasn't able to really fully comprehend enough to adapt to my situation.

Create a third column, multiply the two existing quantity columns and pivot?

If you are not using MS365 then assume you are in Excel 2021 then --> =FILTER(A2:B17,C2:C17) this should work! or older versions: =INDEX(A$2:B$17,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW(C$2:C$17)-1)/C$2:C$17,ROWS(E$1:E1)),)

=filter(table1[[Part]:[QTY]],table1[IN BUILD]) ?

Here is what you could try if using Excel 2021 (Just like commented above)


=FILTER(Table1[[PART]:[QTY]],Table1[IN BUILD])


Or, Older Versions using INDEX()+AGGREGATE()
=INDEX(Table1[[PART]:[QTY]],AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW(Table1[IN BUILD])-1)/Table1[IN BUILD],ROWS(E$1:E1)),COLUMN(A1))


The above formula needs to fill down and fill right, while the FILTER() function doesn't

